# Creating a regular expression to check if word exists?

Tags: c#, regex

1. I want to check whether "help" or " help" (space followed by "help" keyword) or "help " ("help" keyword followed by space) exists in text box input. I want a regular expression for this in C#. (I just want the word "help," not e.g., "helping" or "helped").
2. I want to check whether a sentence starts with the word "how" by using a regular expression.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, post some code

Comment: And if not, do that first.

Answer (score 4):

**To check if a string contains the word '*help*' with a regular expression:**

```
(\s|^)help(\s|$)
```

Explanation:

(\s|^) : With a preceding space, or at the beginning of the file
help   : The word to search for
(\s|$) : With a trailing whitespace, or at the end of the file

**To check if a sentence a start with the word '*how*':**

1. This assumes that there is only one sentence in the string

   ^\s*(how|How)

*Instead of using how|How, you can match case insensitive.*

2. This assumes there are a bunch of sentences, separated by a period

   (.|^)\s*(how|How)

*Again, match case insensitive instead of using how|How if desired.*

Answer (score 0):

C# provides System.Text.RegularExpressions:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"[\ ]?help[\ ]?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Match match = regex.Match("Hello, I need help.help.help .");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    }
    }
}
```

This matches the first occurrence of either of the three possibilities.

The regex for 2 is

```
@"^how"
```